# /INTEGRITYCHECK enabled- Windows Defender blocks self signed exe

Tags: c++, self, code-signing-certificate, makecert, windows-defender

I have enabled the `/INTEGRITYCHECK` linker option for the `C++` exe. And created a self signed test certificate using `makecert` and added it to the trusted root using `CertMgr`. Signed the exe using `Signtool` with this test certificate. But when I am running the signed exe, it is getting blocked by `Windows Defender`.
I am using the instructions from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/255.forced-integrity-signing-of-portable-executable-pe-files.aspx

Actually self signed exe should pass the `/INTEGRITYCHECK` or any other dependency is there? Please help me in this.